# Unzipping Jars to get class .text

Tags: java, jar

I would like to unzip a jar library that I am using check the classes if it's core functionality is updated to what is presented on GitHub.

**How do you unzip a .jar file?**

**Update:**

You wont be able to get class .txt without the source code attached to them if you unzip the directly.

Thanks, to alegen's method of using a Java Decompiler you can decompile classes.

Comment: And what is the question now? Right click -> Extract. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `JAR` file with WinRAR but unless the people also packaged the `source code`, you will only find `.class` files which contain `bytecode`. You will have to also use a `decompiler`; I usually use [JD Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/).

Comment: Thanks, I needed to know the decompiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract files from JAR file using a variety of tools, including plain ZIP file tools ... and of course the `jar` command that comes as part of the JDK.

It sounds like your *real* problem is that you want to decompile the .class files in a JAR file so that you can compare them with some Java source code.

Well, the bad news is that it won't work ... especially in the large-scale.  Yes, there are decompilers that will (on a good day) produce something that resembles Java.  However:

- The decompiled Java won't look anything like the original source code that were used to produce the .class files.  Comparing the decompiled files with the original source code (or something based on the original source code) is going to be a tedious and difficult MANUAL process.
- There is a fair chance that the decompiled code won't even be valid (compilable) Java.

A better approach might be to compile the sourcecode on GitHub and try to compare the two versions of the .class files.  However, even that isn't straight forward because:

- The .class files contain timestamps, and other stuff that depend on build paths, compilation switches, and so on.  You have to figure out how to remove this "noise" when comparing the .class files.
- Different versions of the Java compiler produce different flavours of classfile.
- Even when the classfile version numbers are the same, there can be compiler-version-specific differences in the generated bytecodes.

---

For small-scale comparisons, decompilation might do ... provided you are prepared to work at the problem.  You could also use `javap` to print the bytecodes in the class files and compare the `javap` outputs.

Comment: I just need to see a few method changes and if it decompiles slightly off it would still be fine.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want do do is to check if two jars are the same, to ascertain that the methods on github are the same as the ones in your jar?

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. What you should do is to just check out the code from github and build it yourself. There should be a file called README, INSTALL or something similar in the root directory of the project.

Now, of course, you might not want the newest version of the project, you might want the latest stable release or whatnot, which is perfectly doable: Just download the release you want from git, and build yourself. You now have both the code, and a jar.

If you do this, you are ensured that the code matches the jar, and no icky decompilation is needed, just a quick make or ant later, as specified by the readme file.